# On similar matrices and polynomial matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, polynomials

Let $A,B,P\in M_n(F)$. Suppose that $A$ and $B$ are similar, thus $A=P^{-1}BP$.

If $p(x)=a_0+\ldots+a_nx^n$, and $T:V\to V$ be a linear transformation. Defining $$p(T)=a_0I+\ldots+a_nIT^n$$

How to prove that $$p(A)=P^{-1}p(B)P$$

Thank you very much for any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By linearity (i.e. what is done in detail by **Andreas Caranti**), it suffices to prove it for $p(x)=x^k$.

Now
$$
A^k=(P^{-1}BP)^k=(P^{-1}BP)(P^{-1}BP)\cdots(P^{-1}BP)=P^{-1}B(PP^{-1})B(PP^{-1})\cdots (PP^{-1})BP
$$
$$
=P^{-1}BI_nBI_n\cdots I_nBP=P^{-1}BB\cdots BP=P^{-1}B^kP.
$$
Of course, for a clean proof, use induction on $k$.

**Note:** if you use functional calculus, more generally, for every ad hoc function $f$ on the spectrum of $A$ (which is also the spectrum of $B$), you have $f(A)=P^{-1}f(B)P$.

Comment: Hello. Julien, I did something similar, but then I asked myself, for what reason they gave me that l.t. $T:V\to V$...?

Comment: @SandraWest Hi Sandra. Just to define $p(T)$ in general for any operator $T$. And then it applies to $A$ and $B$.

Comment: So I did one half, and you did the other half. I love team work :-)

Comment: @AndreasCaranti Yes! And within the same minute, plus. Just as if we had a plan.

Answer (score 6):

This is a direct calculation
\begin{align}
P^{-1}p(B)P 
&= P^{-1} (a_0 I + a_1 B + \dots + a_n B^n) P
\\&=
P^{-1} a_0 I P + P^{-1} a_1 B P + \dots + P^{-1} a_n B^n P
\\&=
\dots
\end{align}
where you should use the fact that $P^{-1} B^i P = (P^{-1} B P)^i$, which is detailed in the answer by **julien**.